# How can i fix Error: Cannot find module. Using sequelize, express, node and mysql

Tags: node.js

Can some one help me?

Node v16.15.0
"body-parser": "^1.20.0",
"express": "^4.18.1",
"mysql2": "^2.3.3",
"path": "^0.12.7",
"sequelize": "^6.19.0",
"sequelize-cli": "^6.4.1"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiEUZ.png)

Comment: You don't have an `index.js` in your root of the project

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.